# R: is.integer doesn't work on square root

Tags: r

Basically, I want to check if the square root of a number is an integer, so I tried the following function:

```
is.integer(sqrt(4))
```

The expected value is `TRUE` whereas the actual result is `FALSE`. I have read some other posts and it seems I need to use `L` to force into an integer. However, not sure how should I make it work in my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Even:

```
is.integer(1)
## [1] FALSE
```

because the **type** (opposed to the value) is not integer. Look at the help `?is.integer`. A function `is.wholenumber` is shown there:

```
is.wholenumber <-
     function(x, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5)  
         abs(x - round(x)) < tol
is.wholenumber(sqrt(4))
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Curious as to why you're using √.Machine$double.eps rather than using the epsilon value directly.

Comment: Looks like a somewhat heuristic choice (evidenced by having tol as an optional argument; if they were very sure about the value of tol it would not be a argument)

Comment: I saw that it was just a tol default and would have outright called it wrong if you were taking the root of tol in the method body. The machine default epsilon should generally be less than 1 and taking the root will make it larger causing the default method to be less accurate than configured. Also, if I set the default I'm potentially given a different result than if I pass the same value as a parameter. I realize this isn't code review, but I can't help myself sometimes.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thank you for the solution. However, I'm having trouble to understand your code. What is `.Machine$double.eps`?

Comment: It is not my code. It comes from the help page on `is.integer`. `.Machine$double.eps` is the machine precision. See `?.Machine`. 

In the mean time I have thought about the sqrt. My hypothesis is that this number reflects the number of decimals printed (by default: 7).

Comment: @psaxton: " if I set the default I'm potentially given a different result than if I pass the same value as a parameter".  Really? Can you give a reproducible example of that?  I'm skeptical/surprised ...