# Why would one use this tolerance in is.wholenumber

Tags: r

The help page for `?is.integer` has a note about a function that will tell us if a value is an integer:

```
is.wholenumber <-
   function(x, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5)  abs(x - round(x)) < tol
```

What could be the argument to use `sqrt(eps)` as tolerance here? Also, is there a good reason to use anything else than `tol=0`?

The background is my answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952525/r-is-integer-doesnt-work-on-square-root). Some commenters objected to this function.

My simple minded hypothesis: this is done to make it close in behavior to print (which has a default of 7 decimal digits). E.g.:

```
> 1.000005
[1] 1.000005
> 1.0000000005
[1] 1
> is.wholenumber(1.000005)
[1] FALSE
> is.wholenumber(1.0000000005)
[1] TRUE
```

It does not work perfectly though:

```
> 1.00000005
[1] 1
> is.wholenumber(1.00000005)
[1] FALSE
```

There is a better argument in the comments below: the `sqrt(eps)` may be a (rough) estimate of the round-off error caused by floating-point operations.

Comment: It has nothing to do with printing. It's roughly the amount of precision you can expect from double floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Someone voted to close this question. Can you please explain why? Thanks. (Eager to learn what rule I disobeyed).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thanks. That actually makes sense.

Comment: @Erwin Good point. The voters seem to think that the question is “primarily opinion based”. Of course that’s wrong.

Comment: Looks to me these votes are more "primarily opinion based" than my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare

```
> is.wholenumber(0.6/0.2, tol=0)
[1] FALSE
> is.wholenumber(0.6/0.2)
[1] TRUE
```

While `3 == 0.6/0.3` exactly in reality, it is not so in floating point representation.

From the helpfile for `"=="`

> For numerical and complex values, remember ‘==’ and ‘!=’ do not
>        allow for the finite representation of fractions, nor for rounding
>        error.  Using ‘all.equal’ with ‘identical’ is almost always
>        preferable.

The default tolerance for `is.wholenumber` is set to the same amount as in `all.equal`:

```
 ## S3 method for class 'numeric'
 all.equal(target, current,
           tolerance = .Machine$double.eps ^ 0.5, scale = NULL,
           ..., check.attributes = TRUE)
```

This means that the default behavior of `is.wholenumber` is comparable to

```
isTRUE(all.equal(0,abs(x - round(x))))
```

To take our example full circle

```
> x <- 0.6/0.2
> x
[1] 3
> round(x)
[1] 3
> x == round(x)
[1] FALSE
> isTRUE(all.equal(0,x-round(x)))
[1] TRUE
> isTRUE(all.equal(0,x-round(x), tol=0))
[1] FALSE
```